# Isomorphism of quotient of ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero.  Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are finitely generated $k$-algebras, $I$ is an ideal of $A$ and $J$ an ideal of $B$. Consider the ideal of $A\otimes_kB$ given by
$$ L=I\otimes_k B+A\otimes_k J $$
For each $i\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$ we have a natural map
$$ \bigoplus\limits_{0\leq j\leq i}\left(I^j/I^{j+1}\otimes_k B/J\right)\otimes_{(A\otimes B)/L}\left(A/I\otimes_kJ^{i-j}/J^{j-i+1}\right)\to L^i/L^{i+1}$$
given by multiplication on each summand.  I am quite sure this should be an isomorphism, and I believe it is surjective, but I haven't been able to prove it is injective.  Any ideas?

In the case I am considering $I$ and $J$ are nilpotent ideals, so if that helps then you may assume that.  In fact in my case, $I$ and $J$ are the nilradicals of $A$ and $B$ respectively, and $A/I$ and $B/J$ are integral domains.  You can use that if it's helpful.

Comment: When you say “I believe it is surjective,” do you mean you think you have a proof that it is surjective?

Comment: Yeah,  so if you take an element of $L^i$, you can express it as sum of terms, each of which is an $i$-fold product of $j$ elements of $I\otimes B$ and $i-j$ elements of $A\otimes J$ for some $0\leq j\leq i$.  That should do it.